# Express.js + Google Chrome extension : is session storage possible?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, express

I'm working on a Google Chrome extension with a popup, in which I load a page from a node.js + express.js server. The page I load changes depending on the status of the `req.session.user` in this way:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    if(req.session.user){
        res.render(__dirname + '/pages/base.jade', {});
    }
    else{
        res.render(__dirname + '/pages/login_register.jade', {});
    }
});
```

If `req.session.user` is null I send a page in which the user can do the login or register. If he/she does a login, this is what happens in the server:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    var user = {};
    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.password = req.body.password;
    checkLogin(user, function(foundUser){
        //login correct
        console.log("login!");
        req.session.user = foundUser;
        res.render(__dirname + '/pages/base.jade', {
        });
    });
});
```

So if the user logs in correctly `req.session.user` should be set with the credentials of the current user. The problem is that once I log in and then close the popup of the Chrome extension, whenever I reopen it I still receive the login page.

My question is: does the popup supports session storage in the express.js server? If yes, then there is something wrong with my code, can anyone point out what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

EDIT:

This is how I setup the server:

```
var app = express.createServer(
    express.logger(),
    express.cookieParser(),
    express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' })
);

app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: "keyboard cat" }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set("view options", { layout: true });
```

I might be doing something redundant here, since I still don't have a deep understanding of how that works.

Comment: Express (really, connect) sessions are cookie-based. How is your app set up? Do you `use(express.cookieParser())` and `use(express.session())`? Check that your cookies are working. Perhaps cookies are treated differently in extensions.

Comment: I edited the post with the server setup. As you can see I use `express.session()` and `express.cookieParser()`.

Comment: Ok, that's definitely redundant. I always do `express.createServer()` without parameters and then `.use` all the middlewares etc. Try that and see if it fixes things!

Comment: It worked! It's strange that if you do redundant things it stops working! They should perform some checks on how you set things, or something like that. Anyways thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you have set up your server - you're using the `cookieParser` and `session` middlewares twice:

```
var app = express.createServer(
    express.logger(),
    express.cookieParser(),
    express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' })
);

app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: "keyboard cat" }));
```

You should only use *either* middlewares as parameters to `createServer`, *or* `use`, so:

```
var app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.logger());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: "keyboard cat" }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Popup page probably reloads every time you open it. You should create a backgroundpage for your extension where you could store/manage sessions. Then you can communicate from popup to backgroundpage passing messages [docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html). Using messaging you can send login data to backgroundpage and also ask whether user has already logged in.

Comment: I used that in a previous extension, what I mean in my question was if the server stores the session sent by a popup page. Ideally, if you are navigating through some page and login, then if you reload the page you should still be logged in, right?

Comment: Moreover, I just tried navigating to those pages through the browser and not through the extension (didn't think about this before lol) and it seems it doesn't store the session in the server. The problem is there, the extension it's not the problem I guess.

Comment: How are you identifying authenticated users? If you are using cookies check whether they still exist after popup reopening. If you are using sockets then I think the socket is closed when user closes the popup.

Comment: Users are authenticated on the server side using `req.session.user` which is set if the user logs in correctly. As far as I know it should remember the session of the current user for each user that does a login, but it seems it doesn't work...